# how to link a JBoss server container with SQL server one using docker-compose .yml on centos7 host?

Tags: sql-server, docker, jboss, docker-compose

my host (well in reality virtual machine but never mind) is with Centos 7 I have installed Docker and all its related software, I have pulled and configured (with jboss server) a Centos 7 container, then I have pulled and configured a SQL server 2017 image (linux), I have attached a volume to make databases permanent and finally I have configured a Dockerfile to launch these images at the same time and linked with a network (name "testing"), I have put an application to deploy on the JBoss server and modified the standalone.xml to read the database "Simulation_Test" from the SQL server, here are the standlone.xml (the datasources section)

```
<datasources>
                <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/jboss/datasources/simulation_star1" pool-name="simulation_star1" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://172.22.0.2:1433;databaseName=Simulation_Test</connection-url>
                    <driver>sqlserver</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>SA</user-name>
                        <password>catycaty07X</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                        <background-validation-millis>1</background-validation-millis>
                    </validation>
                    <statement>
                        <prepared-statement-cache-size>0</prepared-statement-cache-size>
                        <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
                    </statement>
                </datasource>
```

the Docker-compose yml

```
version: "3.0"
services:
  webapp1:
    ports:
            - '8080:8080'
            - '9990:9990'
    networks:
            - 'testing'
    links:
            - db1
    image: centoswithjbossconfigured2
  db1:
        environment:
            - 'ACCEPT_EULA: Y'
            - 'MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: catycaty07X'
            - 'MSSQL_PID: Developer'
        ports:
            - '1433:1433'
        volumes:
            - 'my_volume3:/var/opt/mssql/data'
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
volumes:
    my_volume3:
networks:
  testing:
```

and finally the output of the server (Jboss one) when connecting with the deployed application (the error, because the whole output is very long)

```
webapp1_1  | 09:46:23,353 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-6) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component ConnexionService for method public abstract com.star.simulation.dto.AgenceDTO com.star.simulation.service.IConnexionService.connexion(java.lang.String,java.lang.String): javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two containers aren't on the same Docker network.  `webapp1` is on the locally-created `testing` network; `db1` is on the per-stack network Docker Compose creates for you.

I would remove all of the `networks:` and `links:` settings from the `docker-compose.yml` entirely.  Docker Compose will create a network for you and attach all of its containers to that network, and the names `webapp1` and `db1` will be usable as host names.  Once you restart the stack, the fixed IP address you've hard-coded will be wrong.  If you can change it to an environment variable reference that's better, but the host name `db1` should work to reach the database.

Comment: many thanks to you, I have been stuck with my problem for almost 3 days and you sir just saved my life